Dimension of solution space of initial value problem for ODE
I hope this question is not to obvious and I‘m just complelty blacking out.
Given the linear homogenous ODE $y^{(4)} + 2y^{(2)} = 0$
I solved the characteristic polynomial and obtained the homogenous solution:
$f_h(x) = a\cdot e^{i\sqrt{2} x} + b\cdot e^{-i\sqrt{2} x} + c + dx$
Now this without further info has a dimension of 4 (pretty sure about this but please correct me already here if I‘m wrong)
Now given the condition $y(0) = 0$ implies that $a\cdot e^{i\sqrt{2} x} + b\cdot e^{-i\sqrt{2} x} + c = 0$.
Now why does the solution space of the ODE shrink to 3?. I understand that $a\cdot e^{i\sqrt{2} x} + b\cdot e^{-i\sqrt{2} x} + c = 0$ has a solution space of dim 3 (because of three variables Ig) but why can we discard $d$?
Disclaimer: It could well be that I‘m just completly misunderstanding dimension of solution spaces and solution spaces in generel, but I can‘t figure this out

The initial condition implies that $a+b+c=0$. You use this to eliminate one of the variables in the homogenous solution, which reduces it to dim 3.

I knew I was absolutely blacking out on something. Ty so much, time to give my brain a bit of rest

It's a second order linar homogenous equation for y'' with solutions
$$y'' = a \cos x + b \sin x$$ and two more integrations
yield (names of constants free)
$$y= a \cos x + b \sin x + c x +d$$
Four constants to fix $$y(0),y'(0), y''(y),y'''(0)$$
